# Ionic 2 modal does not fill intended space

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ionic2, modal-dialog

I'm creating a dynamic modal to ionic 2 to put small amounts of data in my modal page looks like so:

```
<ion-list>
  <div *ngFor="let propertyInfo of modalOptions.inputMetadata">
    <inline-edit [(ngModel)]="modalOptions.entity && modalOptions.entity[propertyInfo.propertyName]"
                 [label]="propertyInfo.label" [editOptions]="modalOptions.editOptions"
                 [required]="propertyInfo.required" [additionalData]="propertyInfo.additionalData"
                 [type]="propertyInfo.inputType" [componentType]="propertyInfo.componentType">
    </inline-edit>
  </div>
  <ion-list-header>
    <button ion-button full color="secondary">
      Save<ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-list-header>
</ion-list>
```

when I create the modal it appears on screen but does not fill the outline space for the modal:

[image]

Personally I would like to make this have a header with a close button and a footer with a save, but my main question is how do I make this modal fill the intended space?

Comment: Can you post the CSS?

Comment: @robbannn I'm only using the default ionic CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like it was pretty simple, I just needed wrap everything in an  `<ion-content>`

```
<ion-content class="dynamicModal">
  <!--<button outline (click)="close()">Close</button>-->
  <ion-list>
    <div *ngFor="let propertyInfo of modalOptions.inputMetadata">
      <inline-edit [(ngModel)]="modalOptions.entity && modalOptions.entity[propertyInfo.propertyName]"
                   [label]="propertyInfo.label" [editOptions]="modalOptions.editOptions"
                   [required]="propertyInfo.required" [additionalData]="propertyInfo.additionalData"
                   [type]="propertyInfo.inputType" [componentType]="propertyInfo.componentType">
      </inline-edit>
    </div>
    <ion-list-header>
      <button ion-button full color="secondary">
        Save<ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-list-header>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```